# request/requested/requesting date

Tags: american-english

I am developing a website, in which a user can send a request to another user. What's the correct way to describe the date that the request was made on, in the format of **[request/requested/requesting] date**? In addition to a straightforward answer, it would be nice to see some explanation. Thanks.

PS. I can't come up with a better title. Please help on this, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: request date

```
You can see the request date in the rightmost column.
```

- request date = the date on which the request was made
- requested date = the date someone asked about, for instance, if there is a request to send the date of birth of some person, you can respond this way:

  ```
  Please find the requested date in the attached document.
  ```
- And finally, requesting date - does not make much sense (it would mean that the date itself has requested something), except if used like this:

  ```
  I am requesting the date of his move.
  ```

Comment: Thanks Arsen. Here is a follow-up question (hope you don't mind). Say, the request got approved. Should the date the request was approved on be called "approval date" or "approving date"? (Here, I treat "approving" as a gerund)

Answer (score 1):

for your second question you can ether use "approval date" or "date of approval" 
as for the first question Arsen answered it fully :)